# Blazor: How to include npm dependencies into a Razor Class Library?

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, blazor

I am trying to create a Blazor component in a Razor Class Library which uses npm dependencies. In my `wwwroot` I created a `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mycomponent",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^5.14.2"
  }
}
```

In my `csproj` I have:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)wwwroot" />
  </Target>
```

And I set my project to create a .nupkg.

When I now run `dotnet publish MyComponent -c Release`, I get the `MyComponent.1.0.0.nupkg` but its `staticwebassets` folder only has the top level content of `wwwroot` in there.

So, how do I get the dependencies from the `node_modules` folder in there? Do I have to run some sort of packager which generates a minified package in the root folder or am I missing something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which adds webpack to the game. Here is how I did it:

1. If you do not already have a `package.json`, run `npm init` inside `wwwroot` to generate one
2. Move everything in `wwwroot` but `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to `wwwroot/src`
3. Install webpack and some loaders:

   `npm install --save-dev webpack css-loader file-loader style-loader`
4. Add an appropriate `webpack.config.js`:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [ './src/main.js', './src/style.css' ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
            { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, use: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js',
        publicPath: '_content/MyRazorClassLibrary/dist/' // << See note
    }
};
```

Note: The `publicPath` is used for rewriting the path when run inside Blazor. Webpack packs the result in a way that all assets are relative to the main JS file. However Blazor expects the data at the path `_content/ProjectName`, which is accounted for using `publicPath`.

5. Add this to the `csproj` file:

```xml
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)wwwroot" />
    <Exec Command="webpack" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)wwwroot" />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\package-lock.json" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\package.json" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\src\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\webpack.config.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\package-lock.json" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\package.json" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\src\**" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\webpack.config.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This will cause the `src` directory and npm and webpack specific files to not be included in the final NuGet package. Plus, it'll run `npm install` and `webpack`.

For this to work, you must install `webpack-cli`:

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Now, when you run `dotnet build -c Release MyRazorClassLibrary`, and set your library to generate a NuGet package on build, you will get a nice `nupkg` with everything baked in.

Comment: When trying to build I get "Can't resolve './src/main.js'" Where does main.js come from?

Comment: You have to create a main.js yourself. That's the entrypoint of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry there is no support for this in Blazor. Your best approach is to document the requirements on external dependencies for anyone using the library.

I'd point out that not everyone uses NPM (I avoid it like the plague) and have different approaches to client-side packages, so if this is a "public" package it might be too prescriptive an approach to require NPM. If it's internal use only that's fine, but you're on your own as to how to handle bundling and packaging.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5459) tracking how static resources are handled

Comment: I am currently experimenting with using Webpack to package everything up, as I discovered the .bundle.js webpack generated DOES end up in the final nupkg.